How can I add a Line or Separator to a UniformGrid in WPF?
I'm writing an application in C# with WPF. I have a List of Objects in my code that I want to map to a Grid. The List resembles data from a 2D field. The width (x-coordinate) and height (y-coordinate) of the field can change. I'm using an ItemsControl with a UniformGrid as ItemsPanelTemplate. So far, it works.
However, now I want the user to be able to draw a line between two y-coordinates, so for example between y=6 and y=7. The intention is for the user to enter this value in a TextBox, so in this example, the user would enter "6" into the TextBox.
I tried to add a Separator or a Line to the UniformGrid, but unfortunately, that doesn't work. I did get these to work for a Grid with a defined number of columns and rows, but unfortunately, I don't have fixed columns and rows.
I don't know how to get this to work, so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks a lot.
See the code below for the ItemsControl:
<ItemsControl Name="Field" ItemsSource="{Binding visible, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid 
                Columns="{Binding cols}" 
                HorizontalAlignment="left"
                VerticalAlignment="top"
                Name="GridName">
            </UniformGrid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Height="20">
                <TextBlock 
                    Text="{Binding Path=inputEntries.EntryNR}"
                    MouseDown="CellClick"
                    Width="50"
                    TextAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Background="{Binding Path=Intrial, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>


maybe you could fake a line by manipulating BorderBrush and BorderThickness of the ListBoxItem used in the ItemContainerStyle. Respectivly use ItemContainerStyleSelector to provide such ListBoxItems for the rows you want them in, and a different ListBoxItem for the others ...

Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I tested with nested borders (to separate the top border from the other borders) and changing the color of the top border of one specific row based on user input from a TextBox. It is pretty close to what I want to achieve!

I misunderstood exactly what was needed. I left the other answer here because it can be adapted in a way to achieve line drawing on a uniform grid for a type of "selection" but, I really don't recommend doing it that way. I think what we really want is below. You would have to populate your Row/Holder data properly but, the entire row gets selected. You'd also be able to remove objects in the Row dynamically or add data dynamically to the "y" positions. However, you'd still have to select the entire "y" position.
First the view:
<Window.Resources>
        <!-- This styling can be altered but the ControlTemplate is how we are achieving the top and bottom lines on the selected listviewitem. It still needs the contentpresenter -->
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Border x:Name="Bd" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <Grid>
                                <Border x:Name="TopBorder" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" />
                                <Border x:Name="BottomBorder" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" />
                                <ContentPresenter 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="TopBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="BottomBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowVM/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox
            Text="{Binding SelectedCoolObjectHolder.RowID}" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CoolObjectHolders}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCoolObjectHolder}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RowID}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CoolObjects}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <UniformGrid 
                                        Columns="{Binding CoolObjects.Count}">
                                    </UniformGrid>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>

The text changed method(It's not very robust):
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            int.TryParse(((TextBox)sender).Text, out int toTry);
            var selectedRow = viewModel.CoolObjectHolders.FirstOrDefault(x => x.RowID == toTry);
            viewModel.SelectedCoolObjectHolder = selectedRow ?? viewModel.CoolObjectHolders.First();
        }

The ViewModel:
public MainWindowVM()
        {
            //Row Data
            for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
            {
                var newObjectHolder = new CoolObjectHolder(i);
                //Columns Data
                for (int j = 1; j < 8; j++)
                {
                    var toAdd = new CoolObject() { Name = "Value: " + j };
                    newObjectHolder.CoolObjects.Add(toAdd);
                }
                CoolObjectHolders.Add(newObjectHolder);
            }
        }

        

        private ObservableCollection<CoolObjectHolder> _CoolObjectHolders = new();
        public ObservableCollection<CoolObjectHolder> CoolObjectHolders
        {
            get
            {
                return _CoolObjectHolders;
            }
            set
            {
                _CoolObjectHolders = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private CoolObjectHolder _SelectedCoolObjectHolder;
        public CoolObjectHolder SelectedCoolObjectHolder
        {
            get
            {
                return _SelectedCoolObjectHolder;
            }
            set
            {
                _SelectedCoolObjectHolder = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

Finally the Data Model:
public class CoolObjectHolder : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }

            public CoolObjectHolder(int RowID)
            {
                this.RowID = RowID;
            }

            private int _RowID;
            public int RowID
            {
                get { return _RowID; }
                set { _RowID = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
            }

            private ObservableCollection<CoolObject> _CoolObjects = new();
            public ObservableCollection<CoolObject> CoolObjects
            {
                get { return _CoolObjects; }
                set { _CoolObjects = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
            }
        }


        public class CoolObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }

            private string _Name = "";
            public string Name
            {
                get { return _Name; }
                set { _Name = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
            }
        }


If I understand the question correctly you're trying to draw lines between the controls on the uniform grid? You can do this with a canvas and drag and drop. I used your setup you had here but, I modified the code so that it was easier for me to work with. Something it's not currently doing is creating a line that is being drawn with the drag and drop but you could simulate a dummy line on the canvas and then remove it when you call CreateLine in the view model.
This is the MainWindow.xaml
    <Grid>
        <!-- Grid items control -->
        <ItemsControl Name="Field" ItemsSource="{Binding CoolObjects, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid 
                        Columns="7" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="left"
                        VerticalAlignment="top"
                        Name="GridName">
                    </UniformGrid>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Height="20">
                        <TextBlock 
                            Text="{Binding}"
                            Width="50"
                            TextAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Background="Wheat"
                            AllowDrop="True"
                            PreviewMouseMove="TextBlock_PreviewMouseMove"
                            DragDrop.Drop="TextBlock_Drop"/>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>

        <!-- Lines control with Canvas panel -->
        <ItemsControl Name="Lines" ItemsSource="{Binding CoolLines, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      Panel.ZIndex="5">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas
                        Name="CanvasPanel">
                    </Canvas>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Line
                        X1="{Binding X}" X2="{Binding EndX}"
                        Y1="{Binding Y}" Y2="{Binding EndY}"
                        Stroke="Black"
                        StrokeThickness="3">
                    </Line>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>

Here is the view model.
private ObservableCollection<string> _CoolObjects = new();
    public ObservableCollection<string> CoolObjects
    {
        get
        {
            return _CoolObjects;
        }
        set
        {
            _CoolObjects = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public class myLine: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private double _X = 0.0f;
        public double X
        {
            get { return _X; }
            set { _X = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        private double _Y = 0.0f;
        public double Y { 
            get { return _Y; } 
            set {  _Y = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        private double _EndX = 0.0f;
        public double EndX
        {
            get { return _EndX; }
            set { _EndX = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        private double _EndY = 0.0f;
        public double EndY
        {
            get { return _EndY; }
            set { _EndY = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        private Color _Color;
        public Color Color
        {
            get { return _Color; }
            set { _Color = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<myLine> _CoolLines = new();
    public ObservableCollection<myLine> CoolLines
    {
        get
        {
            return _CoolLines;
        }
        set
        {
            _CoolLines = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public void CreateLine(TextBlock sender, TextBlock reciever)
    {
        //Remove this for more lines.
        CoolLines.Clear();
        Point strtPntr = sender.TransformToAncestor(Application.Current.MainWindow)
                         .Transform(new Point(sender.ActualWidth/2, (sender.ActualHeight / 2)));
        Point endPntr = reciever.TransformToAncestor(Application.Current.MainWindow)
                         .Transform(new Point(reciever.ActualWidth / 2, (reciever.ActualHeight / 2)));
        var toAdd = new myLine
        {
            X = strtPntr.X,
            EndX = endPntr.X,
            Y = strtPntr.Y,
            EndY = endPntr.Y,
            Color = Brushes.Black.Color
        };
        CoolLines.Add(toAdd);
    }

and finally the code behind the MainWindow
    public MainWindowVM viewModel;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        viewModel = (MainWindowVM)this.DataContext;
    }

    private void TextBlock_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBlock actualSender = (TextBlock)e.Data.GetData("Sender");
        TextBlock actualReciever = (TextBlock)sender;
        viewModel.CreateLine(actualSender, actualReciever);
    }

    private void TextBlock_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            // Package the data.
            DataObject data = new DataObject();
            data.SetData("Sender", sender);

            // Initiate the drag-and-drop operation.
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, data, DragDropEffects.Copy | DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
    }


Hi Byrd, Thanks for your suggestion, I really appreciate it! I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough in my original question. I want the user to enter an integer into a textbox and have a line shown above that row. So for example, if my field has 10 x coordinates and 20 y coordinates, I would have a grid of 10 columns and 20 rows. If the user types "12" into the textbox, I would like to show a line above the 12th row.
I have been testing a bit with your code and I have learned a lot of new things. I'm quite new to coding, but I'll sure try to continue along your suggested path!

Oh okay. That's much easier than dragging and dropping lines. I'll make another answer haha. This is sort of like a way to "select" a row right?

Thanks a lot. Indeed, it is a way to "divide" everything above and everything below the line. The line is useful as a visual aid for the user.
